# Create multiple processes using clone()

Tags: c, linux, clone

I want to create 3 processes using **clone()** function (instead of **fork()** ) and each process writes his **PID** on standard output. But it only writes parent process and **clone()** doesn't work for some reason. Here's my code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1024

int foo()
{
    printf( "|%d |%d |%d  |%d  |\n", getuid(), getgid(), getpid(), getppid() );
    exit( 1 );
}

int main()
{
    void* stack;
    stack = malloc( STACK_SIZE );
    if( !stack )
    {
        printf( "Stack alloc problem\n" );
        exit( 0 );
    }
    printf( "|UID    |GID    |PID    |PPID   |\n" );
    printf( "|%d |%d |%d  |%d  |Parent\n", getuid(), getgid(), getpid(), getppid() );

    int i = 0;
    for( ; i<3; i++ )
    {
        int err = clone( &foo, ( char * )stack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM, 0 );
        if( err == -1 )
            perror( "clone error" );
    }
    free( stack );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

Comment: `clone()`d processes share the original process's memory space when `CLONE_VM` is used, so you are giving all your clones the same stack to work with.  That doesn't likely explain your observation, but it's bound to cause you trouble.

Comment: So I should create separate stack for each process I create?

Comment: Yes, if the clones share memory then each must have a separate stack.  Also, 1024 bytes is not very much stack space.  How much you need depends on what each clone is going to do, but if you call any library functions then you basically cannot be certain how much you need.  I'd try *at least* ten times as much.

Comment: You should only `free` the stack(s) after all your other threads have finished. Otherwise they may crash.

Comment: @immibis So how do I make them print message before exiting? Why do they do that despite of having `printf` before exit? Could you show me an example of a proper `clone()` function use?

Comment: @immibis the clones start by executing the specified function (`foo()` in this case) and terminate when that function returns.  Or they should. at any rate.  `foo()` ostensibly prints the data

Comment: Your function `foo()` has the wrong signature.  The `clone()` function requires it to accept a parameter of type `void *`, even if it does nothing with the value passed to it.  Fixing that made your code produce some additional output for me (but not the complete output you expected).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've changed `int foo()` to `int foo( void* v )`, but it still gives me the same output.  Doesn't even work with a single `clone()` function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oops, I was thinking of it like `fork`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the several issues already identified in comments:

- children not having their own stacks
- very small stacks
- stack being freed before children are certain to be done with it
- wrong signature for `foo()`

the key problem seems to be that with your particular combination of `clone()` options, your child processes are being treated as threads, not independent processes.  Although the `clone()` call will report their separate PIDs, the main thread cannot `wait()` on them, and when it exits, the other threads are killed.  This can happen before they have a chance to print their output.

Additionally, when the threads concurrently run `printf()`, their output can be intermingled.

It would be better to use `pthread_create()` if you really want to create threads, and `fork()` if you want to create independent child processes.  In either case, there is then a well-defined mechanism to await the children's completion, and well-defined (different) semantics if you choose not to do so.

If you insist on using `clone()` (which is Linux-specific) in the way you are doing, then  you need to roll your own equivalent to `pthread_join()`.  To get the output you're after, you also have to implement mutual exclusion around `foo()`'s call to `printf()`.  I chose to use a semaphore for the first purpose, and having done so, I used another for the mutual exclusion (as opposed to bringing in mutexes as well).

This variation on your original program makes sense and works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

sem_t completion_sem;
sem_t mutex_sem;

int foo(void *p)
{
    sem_wait(&mutex_sem);
    printf("|%d |%d |%d  |%d  |\n", getuid(), getgid(), getpid(), getppid());
    sem_post(&mutex_sem);
    sem_post(&completion_sem);
    return 0;
}

#define NUM_CLONES 3

int main()
{
    void* stack;
    pid_t pid;
    int i;

    if (sem_init(&completion_sem, 0, 0) != 0) {
        perror(NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (sem_init(&mutex_sem, 0, 1) != 0) {
        perror(NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE * NUM_CLONES);
    if (!stack) {
        printf( "Stack alloc problem\n" );
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("|UID    |GID    |PID    |PPID   |\n");
    printf("|%d |%d |%d  |%d  |Parent\n", getuid(), getgid(), getpid(), getppid());

    for (i = 1; i <= NUM_CLONES; i++) {
        int err = clone(&foo, ((char *) stack) + i * STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM, 0);

        if (err == -1) {
            perror( "clone error" );
            sem_post(&completion_sem);  /* avoids hanging later */
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= NUM_CLONES; i++) {
        sem_wait(&completion_sem);
    }
    sem_destroy(&completion_sem);
    sem_destroy(&mutex_sem);

    free(stack);

    return 0;
}
```

The use of `mutex_sem` should be clear enough.

The use of `completion_sem` is a little more complicated, but not much so: it is initialized with value `0`.  Each child posts (increments) it immediately before finishing, and the main thread waits on it once for each child thread.  Thus the main thread cleans up and exits only after each child thread posts.